# I Can't Install Magento On WAMP Server?

Tags: install, permissions, wamp

I'm trying to get to `localhost/magento` using `WAMP` but get the following message:

> You don't have permission to access /magento/ on this server.

Does any know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a WAMP issue, try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. I'm able to access myphpadmin but not magento.

Comment: what is the issue? it may be time out issue

Answer (score 1):

Try using *127.0.0.1* instead of *localhost* while installing magento.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. I'll be honest I'm not entirely sure on how I would go about doing that but I will do the research and try to figure it out. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: During the installation process you have to specify the "Base URL" under "Web access options". There use "127.0.0.1/magento" instead of "localhost/magento"